# No se ha podido conectar al servidor 5 / Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

Tags: mysql

El día de ayer aplique una query:

```
Update mytable
set Column1='Value1'
where Column='Value'
```

y no se por que extraña razón me dejo de funcionar la aplicación solo en mi pc, ya que para los demás usuarios sigue funcionando muy bien, ahora al intentar iniciar mi aplicación con los accesos de mi usuario aparece el siguiente mensaje:

> no se ha podido conectar al servidor 5 / Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

Estoy pensando en que es un problema del puerto que se utiliza que es el 3316... Aunque en lo personal aplicar una `query` en el `MySQL` de este tipo no me debería afectar según yo para nada en la conexión.

**Actualización**

Estas son las condiciones de trabajo:

1. Trabajamos en un ambiente `Windows`.
2. Si tengo acceso al servidor, por medio de ping, acceso remoto e incluso acceso a la base de datos por medio de el programa mencionado `SQL yog ultimate`.
3. El `firewall` esta deshabilitado.
4. Tengo el programa `workbench`.
5. Antes de ejecutar esa query había ejecutado solamente select's yla query update que me causo el error mencionado se ejecuto correctamente y se actualizaron los datos que estaba cambiando.
6. Desde otras PC's si funciona la base de datos muy bien si hay conexión, el error lo marca solo en mi PC y a veces en otros usuarios, pero en los otros usuarios se quita el error y pueden acceder.
7. Generalmente acceso mas por la aplicación que menciono en el punto 2 `SQL yog Ultimate` y por esta si me permite accesar, solamente no me permite accesar por una aplicación de la empresa programada en `VB`, pero esta funciona correctamente en otros usuarios, solo en mi caso no.

Estuve viendo unos log de error en el servidor, que quizás tengan que ver con lo que pasó:

> 160727 17:32:32
>   InnoDB: Error: page 5244 log sequence number 889049262
>   InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 886549248.
>   InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
>   InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
>   InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
>   InnoDB: for more information.

Comment: Tres consideraciones: 1) MySql corre sobre el puerto 3306 y no el 3316, 2) Si corre sobre Windows revise que el firewall este inhabilitado a nivel de servicios 3) chequea por consola accesar mysql con las credenciales con la que la aplicación también accesa

Comment: si es correcto amigo, respecto a lo 1) he estado investigando y vi que si SQL trabaja sobre 3306, pero curiosamente en mi server al ver SQL administrator en server information dice port 3316, respecto a la 2) el firewall esta desahibilitado y si es windows mi pc y el 3) en el servidor puedo accesar por consola con las credenciales y remotamente entro con SQL yog ultimate y como comento todo funcionaba bien hasta que aplique un comando update, estuve tambien viendo los server log y me marca unos errores y que tengo que aplicar forcing-innodb-recovery, gracias por tu respuesta. saludos.

Comment: Posiblemente y por estar definida la Db como InnoDB reporta estar "corrupta" y esto puede estar generando estos errores. En mi caso yo haría un dump de la db y la trataría de montar adicionalmente con otro nombre e intentar accesar la app con esta db temporal a manera de prueba ya que genera más sospechas que a otros usuarios también envía mensajes de alerta y eso definitivamente no es normal y posiblemente la db presente algún tipo de daño.